# String Join treats True as Boolean rather than string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I am writing code to read data from a CSV file to a pandas dataframe and to get the unique values and concatenate them as a string. The problem is that one of the columns contains the values `True` and `False`. So while concatenating the values I am getting the error

> ```
>   sequence item 0: expected str instance, bool found
> ```

I want python to treat `True` as string rather than boolean value.

I have tried many options but none worked.

The full code and a traceback are attached below.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/jaiveeru/Downloads/run_test1.csv')
cols=df.columns.tolist()
for i in cols:
    lst=df[i].unique().tolist()
    str1 = ','.join(lst)
    lst2=[str1]
```

> ```
> ----> 5     str1 = ','.join(lst)
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bool found
> ```

`lst2` should have values `['True,False']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 does not preform implicit casts. You will need to explicitly cast your booleans to strings.

This can be done easily with [`map` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=builtin%20filter#map) which applies a function on each item of an iterable and returns the result:

```
str1 = ','.join(map(str, lst))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.astype(str)`

**Ex:**

```
df[i].unique().astype(str).tolist()
```